# How to do this navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

i want to make a navigation bar similar the one found [here](http://www.geldimweb.net/).

I tried but I couldn't :D

Here's what I did:

```
HTML:
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

CSS
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
li
{
    float:left;
}
a:link,a:visited
{
    display:block;
    width:120px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#98bf21;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
    background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

or you can try the fiddle that i created
http://jsfiddle.net/uYd9u/

Comment: i want to create the same navigation bar as the website link i wrote this one http://www.geldimweb.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/uYd9u/1/

Comment: @oGeez i like it so much but i want the background to be transperent not white:(

Comment: So change the colour - I've given you a start, you're up from here.

Comment: How is this? http://jsfiddle.net/uYd9u/3/

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uYd9u/4/)?

Comment: @oGeez thank you,but i am so sorry i cant make it transparent:(

Comment: ah. got beat... http://jsfiddle.net/uYd9u/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/uYd9u/11/

In order to achieve what you are wanting to create.

```
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:hidden;
border-bottom: 4px solid #98bf21;
    text-align: right; //ADD
}
li
{
display: inline-block; //REMOVE FLOAT:right;
    vertical-align: bottom; //ADD to align to bottom
}
a:link,a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#98bf21;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
li.active,li.active a:link{//ADD so you can have one box have a background.
    background-color:#98bf21; 
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
background-color:#7A991A;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much what if i want to create a drop down menu? in the Contact section? contains 3 links

Comment: According to StackOverflow's format, you should create a new question for that...